# Image updating null using mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am working with image updating api in codeigniter,If i update my image then function is working fine but if i not uploading any image then image field become "Null" in database.Here is my code

```
$add_data['user_id'] = ($this->input->post('user_id') && !empty($this->input->post('user_id'))) ? $this->input->post('user_id') : NULL;

if(!file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) 
                        {
                            $add_data['resume'] = ($this->input->post('resume') && !empty($this->input->post('resume'))) ? $this->input->post('resume') : NULL;

                            $add_data['resume']=$add_data['resume'];
                        }
            else
                        {
                            $filename=time().uniqid(rand()).$_FILES['resume']['name'];
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], "resume/" . $filename);
                            $add_data['resume']=$filename;
                        }

                $data = array(
                'resume'=>$add_data['resume'],
                );  
                $this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
                $query=$this->db->update('users_info', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$filename` is not getting any value and in the database it might have default value `NULL`.

You need to remove/comment this line:

```
...
 $add_data['resume']=$filename; // <-- $filename is not getting any value,  uncomment or remove it.
}
else
{    
...
```

Comment: i just want that if i not uploaded any new image then old image should not delete from db

Comment: @amitsharma, if you do not specify the field in edit array, it will not update the old value.

Comment: Answer updated. If file is not uploaded, we don't need to update value in database.

Comment: you are right but my value in database become null automatically,how i can fix this